# What logic is used to generate an application hang event 1002

Tags: windows, freeze

I would like to understand what logic does Microsoft uses to identify if an application has hanged and then generate the eventid=1002, Source = Application hang.

Is this event generated only for UI based application or Is it also applicable to windows Services?

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=1002&EvtSrc=Application+Hang&LCID=1033

```
Event Information:
Product:    Windows Operating System
Event ID:   1002
Source: Application Hang
Version:    5.2
Symbolic Name:  ER_HANG_LOG
Message:    Hanging application %1, version %2, hang module %3, version %4, hang address 0x%5.

Explanation
The indicated program stopped responding. The message contains details on which program
and module stopped responding. A matching event with EventID 1001 might also appear in the
event log. This matching event displays information about the specific error that
occurred.
```

Comment: The desktop window manager detects this, backgrounder is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx